# Ruby_on_rails session and syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I'm new to rails. Looking at code (for a filter on data) someone else has written. Trying to figure out what exactly the following mean:

1. `session[:filters]` - just a hash with the chosen filters from the session? is :filters a session option or defined in the code somewhere?
2. `session[:filters][controller]` - same as 1) but specifying the controller?
3. `session[:filters][controller][session[:user]]` -??
4. `session[:filters][controller].delete(session[:user])` -??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically [`session`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-storage) is a `Hash` object used by rails to store data as a cookie on client-side, and, as a `Hash`, it uses `keys` to store information (more information on hashes [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html)).

In your code, `:filters` is just a `key` of the `session` hash (you can tell because of the `:`), and it contains information regarding, i assume, filters. So `:filters` is not defined anywhere else, although it should be set somewhere else, with something like:

```
session[:filters] = some_filter
```

In the second line you see `[:filters][controller]`, that means that `:filters` is also a `Hash`, and as such it also contains keys, one of them being the name of the controller (again, i assume it is because of the name, but i could be wrong). Here `controller` is just a variable (notice there is no `:`) which contains the name of a `key` for the `:filters` hash.

So, if you are following along, you can tell now that whatever `controller` value is, is another `Hash`. In line 3 `session[:user]` is a key for that hash (where `:user` is another key of the `session` hash, which i assume holds the user name or id).

Finally, in line 4 `delete` deletes the key `session[:user]` from the hash (i.e. removes it from the cookie).

Consider this example:

```
# create session hash with :user key
session = { :user => "user79" }
#=> {:user=>"user79"}

# create another hash with session[:user] key and any value
hash1 = { session[:user] => "my value" }
#=> {"user79"=>"my value"}

# create controller variable with a value
controller = "users"
#=> "users"

# create another hash with controller key and hash1 as a value
hash2 = { controller => hash1 }
#=> {"users"=>{"user79"=>"my value"}}

# add :filters key to session with hash2 as a value
session[:filters] = hash2

# Retrieve the value from the session hash
session[:filters][controller][session[:user]]
#=> "my value"

# Delete session[:user] key from the session hash
session[:filters][controller].delete(session[:user])
#=> "my value" (delete returns the deleted value)

# Retrieve the value from the session hash
session[:filters][controller][session[:user]]
#=> nil

session[:filters][controller]
#=> {}  (returns empty hash since we deleted the only key it had)
```

Comment: @user7934228 Glad to help! If you find the answer complete, you can accept it (clicking on the tick). :)